# High Order Bits - Take them and make a uint64_t into a uint8_t

Tags: c++, c, assembly, bit-manipulation

Let's say you have a uint64_t and care only about the high order bit for each byte in your uint64_t.  Like so:

uint32_t:
0000 ... 1000 0000 1000 0000 1000 0000 1000 0000 ---> 0000 1111

Is there a faster way than:

```
   return
   (
     ((x >> 56) & 128)+
     ((x >> 49) &  64)+
     ((x >> 42) &  32)+
     ((x >> 35) &  16)+
     ((x >> 28) &   8)+
     ((x >> 21) &   4)+
     ((x >> 14) &   2)+
     ((x >>  7) &   1)
   )
```

Aka shifting x, masking, and adding the correct bit for each byte?  This will compile to a lot of assembly and I'm looking for a quicker way...  The machine I'm using only has up to SSE2 instructions and I failed to find helpful SIMD ops.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could reinterpret the single bytes, loop through them and mask out the single bits. dunno if this is faster, but maybe the compiler can optimize it better.

Comment: Perhaps you can first mask with `0x8080808080808080` and then multiply by a particular constant to put the bits in more convenient locations, perhaps for use in a lookup table.

Comment: Do you need the result, that is, a sequence of 8 bits as a number? Or would just checking if the HO bits are `1` or not, suffice for you?

Comment: Yes, `pmovmskb` does exactly what you want. IIRC there will be an integer instruction in AVX2 that you can use to do the same thing (gathers bits, forgot the mnemonic).

Comment: harold, you should really make that an answer, not a comment.  It's absolutely correct, on Intel the SSE instruction is what you want.  Note that there is an AVX encoding for it already, though it works only over the bottom 16 bytes of the ymm register.

Comment: @AndyRoss I was in the process of writing it, took a while because I *really* wanted to put that new instruction in there :)

Comment: OP's machine lacks anything past SSE2, so while the new way is nice, it's probably not relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, `pmovmskb` does what you want. Here's how you could use it:

MMX + SSE1:

```
movq mm0, input ; input can be r/m
pmovmskb output, mm0 ; output must be r
```

SSE2:

```
movq xmm0, input
pmovmskb output, xmm0
```

And I looked up the new way

BMI2:

```
mov rax, 0x8080808080808080
pext output, input, rax ; input must be r
```

Comment: +1 if you add the correct inline asm (with proper constraints) to generate optimal code using this method.

Comment: @R.. I would, but I've never done that before. I try not to touch GCC with a 10-foot pole. I had a look at those constraints and, well, maybe that code will appear in while.. maybe

Comment: OK +1 anyway. I'll add it if I get time to look into how to do it.

Comment: Isn't there a simple intrinsic for this asm?

Comment: @rubenvb you tell me. I've never figure out how to `MOVQ` from a register with intrinsics.

Answer (score 11):

```
return ((x & 0x8080808080808080) * 0x2040810204081) >> 56;
```

works. The & selects the bits you want to keep. The multiplications all the bits into the most significant byte, and the shift moves them to the least significant byte. Since multiplication is fast on most modern CPUs this shouldn't be much slower than using assembly.

Comment: This could actually be faster than `pmovmsk`, which is a quite slow instruction AFAIR.

Comment: @drhirsch 2 cycle latency (3 on AMD K10) and a throughput of 1 on a Core2, not that bad at all.. even just the multiplication here is worse.

Comment: For 32-bit integers, the constant is `0x2204081` like so: `return ((x & 0x80808080) * 0x2204081) >> 28;`

Answer (score 5):

And here's how to do it using SSE intrinsics:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  uint64_t x
  = 0b0000000010000000000000001000000000000000100000000000000010000000;

  printf ("%x\n", _mm_movemask_pi8 ((__m64) x));
  return 0;
}
```

Works fine with:

```
gcc -msse
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need all the separate logical ANDs, you can simplify it to:

```
x &= 0x8080808080808080;
return (x >>  7) | (x >> 14) | (x >> 21) | (x >> 28) |
       (x >> 35) | (x >> 42) | (x >> 49) | (x >> 56);
```

(assuming that the function return type is `uint8_t`).

You can also convert that to an unrolled loop:

```
uint8_t r = 0;

x &= 0x8080808080808080;

x >>= 7; r |= x;
x >>= 7; r |= x;
x >>= 7; r |= x;
x >>= 7; r |= x;
x >>= 7; r |= x;
x >>= 7; r |= x;
x >>= 7; r |= x;
x >>= 7; r |= x;
return r;
```

I'm not sure which will perform better in practice, though I'd tend to bet on the first - the second might produce shorter code but with a long dependency chain.

Comment: And the million-dollar question is: does `gcc -msse` generate `pmovmskb` for this code? :)

Comment: You'll probably want to qualify that constant as `ULL` so the compiler doesn't try to play tricks with signed values.

Comment: @MarkB: That's not necessary in C++11.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ULL is never needed.

Comment: It's not necessary in C99 either - since `x` is unsigned, even if the constant is signed it will be promoted to unsigned (this is true even if the type of the constant is wider than `uint64_t`).

Answer (score 2):

First you don't really need so many operations.  You can act on more than one bit at a time:

```
x = (x >> 7) & 0x0101010101010101; // 0x0101010101010101
x |= x >> 28;                      // 0x????????11111111
x |= x >> 14;                      // 0x????????????5555
x |= x >>  7;                      // 0x??????????????FF
return x & 0xFF;
```

An alternative is to use modulo to do sideway additions.  The first thing is to note that `x % n` is the sum of the digits in base `n+1`, so if `n+1` is `2^k`, you are adding groups of k bits. If you start with
`t = (x >> 7) & 0x0101010101010101` like above, you want to sum groups of 7 bits, thus `t % 127` would be the solution. But `t%127` works only for result up to 126. 0x8080808080808080 and anything above will gives incorrect result.  I've tried some corrections, none where easy.

Trying to use modulo to put us in the situation where there is just the last step of the previous algorithm to was possible. What we want is to keep the two less significant bits, and then have the sum of the other one, grouped by 14. So

```
ull t = (x & 0x8080808080808080) >> 7;
ull u = (t & 3) | (((t>>2) % 0x3FFF) << 2);
return (u | (u>>7)) & 0xFF;
```

But t>>2 is t/4 and << 2 is multiplying by 4.  And if we have `(a % b)*c == (a*c % b*c)`, thus `(((t>>2) % 0x3FFF) << 2)` is `(t & ~3) % 0xFFFC`. But we also have the fact that a + b%c = (a+b)%c if it is less than c. So we have simply `u = t % FFFC`. Giving:

```
ull t = ((x & 0x8080808080808080) >> 7) % 0xFFFC;
return (t | (t>>7)) & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
return (x & 0x8080808080808080) % 127;
```

Comment: Not if you have the first bit set and thus need an answer >= 128.