# High Order Bits- Drop them and shift right

Tags: c++, c, assembly, bit-manipulation

As a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181352/high-order-bits-take-them-and-make-a-uint64-t-into-a-uint8-t):

Let's say you have a uint64_t and care only about the NON-high order bits for each byte in your `uint64_t`. Like so:

```
0111.1111 0111.1111 0111.1111 0111.1111 0111.1111 0111.1111 0111.1111 0111.1111
```

--->

```
0000.0000 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1111
```

Is there a faster way to shift each 7 bit section to the right than masking each section out, shifting right, and adding to the next?

Unfortunately, I don't have the hot AVX instructions that allow for fast and general bit gathering; I only have access to SSE2 instructions.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with three mask and shifts.

```
u64 val;

// remove bits at 7, 23, 39, 47
u64 odd8   = val & 0x7f007f007f007f00L;
u64 even8  = val & 0x007f007f007f007fL;

val = ( odd8 >> 1 ) | even8;

// remove bits at 15-16, 23-24
u64 odd16  = val & 0x3FFF00003FFF0000L;
u64 even16 = val & 0x00003FFF00003FFFL;

val = ( odd16 >> 2 ) | even16;

// remove bits at 31-35
u64 odd32  = val & 0x0FFFFFFF00000000L;
u64 even32 = val & 0x000000000FFFFFFFL;

val = ( odd32 >> 4 ) | even32;
```